# How can I update the title?

Tags: lightbox2

I have the following code :

```
<a id="plop" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="aaa" href="https://unsplash.it/300/300">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="" />
</a>
```

I want to change the "data-title" from "aaa" to "bbb" using something like this : 
`$('#plop').data('title','bbb');`
But when I click on the link, the lightbox displays the old title :-/

How can I update the title with the new value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbox reads the attribute and not the jQuery data store.

To update the title, try the following: `$('#plop').attr('data-title', 'bbb')`.

Comment: @LudovicMartin np! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct to help future visitors. :-)

Comment: Oops sorry. Done ;-)